# How to filter the nodes in Neo4j using the relationship property that is of type List

Tags: neo4j

How to retrieve all the influencers for a specific user and based on specific property in a relationship defined for example in the below example I want retrieve all the influencers for p1 in prid= 'c1' and projects IN only PR1?

Sample Data Set

```
 CREATE (p1:People {name:'P1 User',  id: 'p001'})
CREATE (p2:People {name:'P2 User',  id: 'p002'})
CREATE (p3:People {name:'P3 User',  id: 'p003'})
CREATE (p4:People {name:'P4 User',  id: 'p004'})
CREATE (p5:People {name:'P5 User',  id: 'p005'})

CREATE
      (p1)<-[:INFLUENCER {prid:'c1', projects:['PR1','PR2']}]-(p2),
      (p1)<-[:INFLUENCER {prid:'c1', projects:['PR1','PR4']}]-(p3),
      (p1)<-[:INFLUENCER {prid:'c1', projects:['PR1']}]-(p4),
      (p2)<-[:INFLUENCER {prid:'c1', projects:['PR1']}]-(p3),
      (p3)<-[:INFLUENCER {prid:'c1', projects:['PR4','PR5']}]-(p4),
      (p4)<-[:INFLUENCER {prid:'c1', projects:['PR4','PR5']}]-(p5)

 MATCH (p:People{gsid:'p001'})<-[r:INFLUNCED_BY]-(:People)
    WHERE r.prid='c1' AND r.projects IN ['PR1']
    RETURN p,r;
```

The above query is returning no records even though the following relationships exists

```
MATCH (node) RETURN node;
```

[image: The result for the above query]

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please refer to the edit post

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not have the same names for the properties of nodes and type of relationships in the query:

```
gsid vs id
INFLUNCED_BY vs INFLUENCER
```

Second, you need to check the intersection of the lists, not the occurrence. So according to the test data:

```
MATCH (p:People {id:'p001'})<-[r:INFLUENCER]-(:People)
WHERE r.prid ='c1' AND 
      // Check the lists for intersection
      any(p IN r.projects WHERE p IN ['PR1'])
RETURN p, r;
```